# Get special group in pandas multiindex

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have a DataFrame with MultiIndex like this:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
                 a   b
lvl0 lvl1 lvl2
A0   B0   C0     0   1
          C1     2   3
          C2     4   5
          C3     6   7
     B1   C0     8   9
          C1    10  11
          C2    12  13
          C3    14  15
A1   B0   C0    16  47
          C1    18  49
          C2    20  41
          C3    22  43
     B1   C0    24  25
          C1    26  27
          C2    28  29
          C3    30  31
A2   B0   C0    32  33
          C1    34  35
          C2    36  37
          C3    38  39
     B1   C0    40  41
          C1    42  43
          C2    44  45
          C3    46  47
```

I want get the special *lvl1* group in each *lvl0* index. In this case, choice the group where column *b* has max value, result may like this:

```
                 a   b
lvl0 lvl1 lvl2
A0   B1   C0     8   9
          C1    10  11
          C2    12  13
          C3    14  15
A1   B0   C0    16  47
          C1    18  49
          C2    20  41
          C3    22  43
A2   B1   C0    40  41
          C1    42  43
          C2    44  45
          C3    46  47
```

Is there a indexing method like `df[(('A0','B1'),('A1','B0'),('A2','B1')),:]`? I have try my best, Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
df1 = df.reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
mask = df1.index.isin(df1.groupby(level=[0])['b'].idxmax())
df = df[mask]

print (df)
                 a   b
lvl0 lvl1 lvl2        
A0   B1   C0     8   9
          C1    10  11
          C2    12  13
          C3    14  15
A1   B0   C0    16  47
          C1    18  49
          C2    20  41
          C3    22  43
A2   B1   C0    40  41
          C1    42  43
          C2    44  45
          C3    46  47
```

Explanation:

First remove 3 level of `MultiIndex` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices of max values in column `b`:

```
df1 = df.reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
idx = df1.groupby(level=[0])['b'].idxmax()
print (idx)
 lvl0
A0    (A0, B1)
A1    (A1, B0)
A2    (A2, B1)
Name: b, dtype: object
```

Then create boolean mask by compare by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
print (df1.index.isin(idx))
[False False False False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
 False False False False False False False False  True  True  True  True]
```

and last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df1.index.isin(idx)]
print (df)
                 a   b
lvl0 lvl1 lvl2        
A0   B1   C0     8   9
          C1    10  11
          C2    12  13
          C3    14  15
A1   B0   C0    16  47
          C1    18  49
          C2    20  41
          C3    22  43
A2   B1   C0    40  41
          C1    42  43
          C2    44  45
          C3    46  47
```

Comment: Yes, groupby and boolean indexing is the right way.